# Do not render chart when no data is found or display a message or something similar

Tags: zingchart

I'm using the drilldown pie chart to drill down into children of a node, etc. The problem is that at some point, the children do not contain any data. Is there a way to display a message or something similar inside the chart instead of a white area (because of no series data) that informs the user that there is no more data to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question! Inside of your JSON configuration you can define the `nodata` attribute.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: "bar", 
  noData:{
    text:"Empty Series",
    backgroundColor: "#20b2db"
  },
  series:[
      {
        values:[]
      }
    ]
};
 
zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: 400, 
 width: 600 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
    </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can even use background image like a loading screen. In the following example I'm displaying spongebob while I'm waiting for chart data to come in. So I initially render a chart with no series values and nodata defined. The image is displayed while the Ajax call happens asynchronously.

[demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/X6SJYB3E)